# MySQL query - all combinations without duplicates or reverse order duplicates

Tags: mysql

I have a query that returns all possible combinations from 5 columns. The problem is I want to remove duplicates (Car | Car) and reserve order duplicates (Truck | Car) if (Car | Truck) already exists. I’ve played around with DISTINCT, but haven’t had any luck.

Sample Data:

[Sample data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J89Vc.png)

| wdt_id | column1 | column2 | column3 | column4 | column5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Car | Car |  | Cat |  |
| 2 | Truck | Truck |  | Dog |  |
| 3 | Plane | Plane |  | Bird |  |

Query:

```
SELECT
    item1, item2, item3, item4, item5
    ,concat_ws('<br>',NULLIF(item1,''),NULLIF(item2,''),NULLIF(item3,''),NULLIF(item4,''),NULLIF(item5,'')) as combination
FROM (
    SELECT column1 AS item1
    FROM sample_data
) AS t1
CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT column2 AS item2
    FROM sample_data
) AS t2
CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT column3 AS item3
    FROM sample_data
) AS t3
CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT column4 AS item4
    FROM sample_data
) AS t4
CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT column5 AS item5
    FROM sample_data
) AS t5
GROUP BY
    item1, item2, item3, item4, item5
    ,concat_ws('<br>',IFNULL(item1,''),IFNULL(item2,''),IFNULL(item3,''),IFNULL(item4,''),IFNULL(item5,''))
```

Update:

A simplified example of output using just two columns.

Data:

```
column1|column2
Car|Car
Truck|Truck
Plane|Plane
```

Output:

```
Car|Truck
Car|Plane
Truck|Plane
```

Comment: Update your post with the expected output.

Comment: is '' a thing that should be included in the output eg cat,''

Comment: @P.Salmon, No the '' are blank and should not be included.

Comment: not sure your amended sample helped - you seem to want pairs of unique 'things' rather than what I first thought which was combinations within wdt_id

Comment: Not `CROSS JOIN` but `INNER/LEFT JOIN ON lefttable.column < righttable.column`.

Comment: @p.salmon, Correct, unique combinations. No duplicates / reverse order duplicates

Comment: @Akina. Do you have an example? Not sure I understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First unvpivot with UNION which also dedupes then concat then select distinct

```
with cte as
(
select wdt_id,column1 col from t where column1 <> ''
union
select wdt_id,column2 col from t where column2 <> ''
union
select wdt_id,column3 col from t where column3 <> ''
union
select wdt_id,column4 col from t where column4 <> ''
union
select wdt_id,column5 col from t where column5 <> ''
),
cte2 as
(
select case when cte.col < cte1.col then concat(cte.col,'/',cte1.col) 
            else concat(cte1.col,'/',cte.col)
         end as paired
from cte
join cte cte1 on cte1.col <> cte.col

)
select distinct paired from cte2
order by paired
;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/LVE3Qj1T